# Why does 'flatpak install' change the repo URL?

Tags: flatpak

I am building my own flatpak application in a Focal VM, and it seems to work fine. However, I just created a second Focal VM, and even though it should be identical, it fails in some weird ways. Specifically, when I try to install my application from its own local build repository, flatpak changes the repo's URL to flathub!

Example:

```
$ flatpak remotes --user -d
Name      Title   URL                           Collection ID
buildrepo         file:///path/to/buildrepo     org.flathub.Stable
flathub   Flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo   org.flathub.Stable

$ flatpak remote-ls --user buildrepo
Name        Application ID                       Version       Branch
myapp       com.example.myapp                                  master

$ flatpak install --user buildrepo com.example.myapp
error: No remotes found which provide these refs: [(org.flathub.Stable, app/com.example.myapp/x86_64/master)]

$ flatpak remotes --user -d
Name      Title   URL                          Collection ID
buildrepo         https://dl.flathub.org/repo/ org.flathub.Stable
flathub   Flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo  org.flathub.Stable
```

As you can see, the URL changes from `file:///path/to/buildrepo` to `https://dl.flathub.org/repo/` somehow. That most definitely smells like a bug to me, but the fact that this works on one Focal VM and not another also seems like there could be some kind of configuration issue? Both VMs are running flatpak 1.6.5 and flatpak-builder 1.0.10. Anyone seen anything like this?